# Show part of Image (sub-image in image strip) without squishing it?

Tags: javascript, html, image, sprite

I have an image on a webpage. It's a pretty big image, however. It's 6144*768. In actuality, it is a series of 6 images mushed together.

I read that it's better practice to load this one image instead of loading 6 images. I've found this to be true as well, when I used tables and CSS.

However, when I set this image as the source of an image element and then set the size of the image element to 1024*768, the image is squished. Ack!

How can I get this image to be not-squished by using only Javascript? Also, how could I move the background of the image?

[example: Imagine a really long strip of paper. Then, place a small cut-out rectangle of paper over that somewhere on the strip of paper, so that you can only see the part of the strip that is inside the rectangle. This is what I want to do]

Comment: Just don't set the size of the image in the CSS; it should scale properly on its own.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: But really he wants to crop the image to get 1 of the 6 present in the full sized version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the image inside a container element, and set the overflow to hidden using CSS.
Leave the image as it is and it won't be squished

## HTML

> ```
> <div id="imgContainer">
>     <img src="myImage.jpg" alt="" width="6144" height="768" />
> </div>
> ```

## CSS

> ```
> #imgContainer
> {
>     height: 1024px;
>     width: 768px;
>     overflow: hidden;
> }
> ```

Then to move the image use negative values for the CSS style `margin-left`.

> ```
> #imgContainer img
> {
>     margin-left: -1024px;
> }
> ```

You can do this with jQuery as follows

> ```
> $("#imgContainer img").css("margin-left", "-1024px")
> ```

Answer (score 1):

What OP is looking for is [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) (also see [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) or [Smashingmag](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/)).

Comment: How would I do this? I believe that's what I'm already doing - but my image is squished.

Comment: "I believe that's what I'm already doing" > Probably you're doing *something* wrong. As long as you don't post code we can only guess to what's wrong (we're not clearvoyant) and point you in the right direction. Did you follow the instructions on [the links I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10038184/215042)? Could you post your (relevant pieces of) html/css?

Comment: This is overly complicated, the matter is actually pretty simple. See my answer.

Comment: @Robill: Yeh, you were right, I did something wrong. I changed the margin of my image and not of the div. Anyhow, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't scale your image with CSS; instead, put it in a wrapper div and do something like this in your CSS:

```
#myImageWrapper {
    height: 1024;
    width: 768;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Is there anything else that I should do with this wrapper div?

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp: This goes without saying, but you created a div with an id of 'myImageWrapper' and put your image element inside of it?

Comment: The only problem I see is how will the OP display image 2, 3, ...?  He would need an offset to be applied as well.  Take this with a grain of salt as I am not a web guy.

Comment: Yes, that's what he'd have to do. There are plugins written for jQuery that do this (animated, even!) and it's not all that hard to do with vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Okay, I found the problem: I was setting the margin of my image instead of the margin of my div. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, oops. It's the little stuff that gets you, huh? :)